# Extracting the relevant text from an email stored in pandas column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, email

I have a situation in which there are several emails that are stored in a pandas column, some emails are lengthy and some are precise. I wanted to understand how to extract the actual body of that email, even if there are multiple responses on the same email. For example:

df:

```
 email                                                                        clean_email
                                                                              Query Hello Please can someone advise?
<xx@gmail.com> Sent: 10 January 2021 13:12 To: yy@gmail.com>
Query Hello Please can someone advise?
```

I want to achieve the output as shown in the clean_email column. Is there a method to achieve this sort of transformation? There are around 10k emails in this email column with probably different email structures. The ask is to extract the actual body from these emails

Comment: You can use regex; but for that you need to find out all kinds of variations in patterns e.g. the above example does not show; but there can be a `cc` field with one or more email ids etc. Also, in case of multiple responses, you have to split by email header. You might want to show multiple data samples for a better answer.

Comment: You can try using email.message_from_string from the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html)